# Create a named structure with a column of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this structure, `data`:

```
    req_ID effort satisfaction
1     r01      1           62
2     r02      4           55
3     r03      2           29
4     r04      3           41
```

I want to create a named vector of `0s` with the first column, Is there other way to create this instead of this?:

```
mochila <- (rep(0, nrow(data)))
names(mochila) <- c(data$req_ID)
```

Result:

```
> mochila
r01 r02 r03 r04 
  0   0   0   0
```

Comment: @bouncyball Wow, so much thanks, post this as an answer to accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this in one line using the [`numeric`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/numeric.html) and [`setNames`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html) functions:

```
mochila <- setNames(numeric(nrow(data)), data$req_ID)

# r01 r02 r03 r04 
#   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: I was commenting you to post your comment haha, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's much better, but you can do:

```
mochila <- vector(length = nrow(data), mode = "integer")
```

and then same `names` command